# Trigger command when ListBox selected item changes

Tags: wpf, xaml, listbox

I am trying to set up a sort of menu using ListBox and buttons as ListBoxItems to trigger a command when selection changes, but the result is that some times the selected ListBoxItem is changed but the command is not triggered, other times the opposite. The XAML is the following:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:TripViewModel}">
        <views:TripView />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:AddTripViewModel}">
        <views:AddTripView />
    </DataTemplate>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Height"
                Value="50" />
        <Setter Property="Background"
                Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Border>
                        <Grid Background="Transparent">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                              VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="Padding"
                Value="3" />
        <Setter Property="Background"
                Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                    <Border BorderBrush="Transparent"
                            BorderThickness="0"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                          VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                                 Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background"
                                    Value="DarkCyan" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected"
                                 Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background"
                                    Value="DarkCyan" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Window.Content>
    <DockPanel Margin="0"
               HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
               VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
               Height="Auto"
               Width="Auto"
               LastChildFill="True">

        <!-- Left Panel -->
        <Border BorderBrush="Black"
                BorderThickness="0,0,1,0">
            <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Left"
                        Margin="0"
                        Background="#555D6F">

                <!-- First Row: Stacco Image -->
                <Image Height="183"
                       Width="275"
                       Margin="3"
                       Source="/Media/stacco.png" />

                <!-- Second Row: Buttons -->
                <ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="True"
                              VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                              Margin="0,10,0,0">
                    <ListBox Name="MenuButtons"
                             ItemsSource="{Binding PageViewModels}"
                             Background="#555D6F"
                             IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <ItemContainerTemplate>
                                <Button Content="{Binding Name}"
                                        Command="{Binding DataContext.ChangePageCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
                                        Margin="0" />
                            </ItemContainerTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>

        <!-- Control Area: Different View made by controls -->
        <ContentControl DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                        Content="{Binding CurrentPageViewModel}" />
    </DockPanel>
</Window.Content>
```

Am I doing right trying to insert a button in the ItemContainerTemplate? Would it be better to use the code behind to trigger the selection changed?

Comment: It doesn't seem to make much sense to have a Button when you just want to handle the SelectionChanged event. The most simple approach would probably be to bind the ListBox's `SelectedItem` property to a property in your view model.

Comment: Like @Clemens said, put the command in the `SelectedItem` property setter. this way it will trigger the command every time.

Comment: "put the command in the SelectedItem property setter" is a little misleading, and I didn't say that. While you may perhaps *execute* the command in the property setter, it's much simpler to drop the entire command, and directly call the command's execute method.

Comment: Have a look at MM8 answer here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45028898/using-a-combobox-to-select-data-for-a-datagrid)