# Using a ComboBox to select data for a DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, datagrid

In my XAML I have a ComboBox which selects a parent element. Selection of an item in the ComboBox should populate a DataGrid with children elements which belong to the selected parent from the ComboBox (I hope this makes sense).

```xml
<!-- Select here to populate datagrid -->
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ContactGroups}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Name"
          SelectedValuePath="Id"
          SelectedValue="{Binding ContactGroup}" />

<!-- ComboBox selection loads data to the grid -->
<DataGrid ItemsSource={Binding Contacts}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding FirstName}" Header="First Name" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding LastName}" Header="Last Name" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

I had wanted to just use databinding and my ViewModel to do this, but I honestly have no idea how to pass the selected ContactGroup Id to my ViewModel which I've set up with the following:

```
public class ContactsViewModel
{
    private readonly ObservableCollection<Contact> _Contacts
        = new ObservableCollection<Contact>();
    public IEnumerable<Contact> Contacts
    {
        get { return _Contacts; }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<ContactGroup> _ContactGroups 
        = new ObservableCollection<ContactGroup>();
    private IEnumerable<ContactGroup> ContactGroups
    {
        get { return _ContactGroupsViewModel; }
    }

    // Binding for ContactGroups ComboBox
    public ICommand ListContactGroupsCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new MyDelegateCommand(ListContactGroups);
        }
    }
    private void ListContactGroups()
    {
        using (ApplicationDbContext Context = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            var ContactGroups = Context.ContactGroups.Where
            (
                x => x.Deleted == false
            );

            foreach (var c in ContactGroups)
            {
                AddToContactGroups(c);
            }
        }
    }
    private void AddToContactGroups(ContactGroup group)
    {
        if (!_ContactGroups.Contains(group))
            _ContactGroups.Add(group);
    }

    // Handle selection of a ContactGroup.
    public ICommand ListContactsForGroupCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new MyDelegateCommand((ContactGroupId) =>
                { ListContacts((int)ContactGroupId); });
        }
    }

   private void ListContacts(int contactGroupId)
    {
        using (ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            var Contacts = db.Contacts.Where
            (
                x => x.ContactGroupId == contactGroupId &&
                x.Deleted == false
            );
            foreach (var c in Contacts)
            {
                AddToContacts(c);
            }
        }
    }
    private void AddToContacts(Contact contact)
    {
        if (!_Contacts.Contains(contact))
            _Contacts.Add(contact);
    }
}
```

How can I execute my `ListContactsForGroupCommand` on the ComboBox?

I figured I can hook it into the `SelectionChanged` event, but I see now way to provide a parameter value.

Can I do this from the code-behind?

Comment: The code of ContactGroupsViewModel would help

Comment: `ContactGroup` setter is called when another item is selected in combobox. You don't need command nor event. The only caution is to not call the setter from code behind (e.g. when setting initial value), for this you can have another property (or just set field and rise notification for property to update bindings).

Comment: @RomanoZumbé in what way exactly would it help? I don't wish to be difficult but from the code I've provided, its obvious that it contains an Id and Name property which I'm trying to use. I don't understand how having that code will help you to help me achieve what I'm attempting. Could you explain?

Comment: @Ortund The propertiy `ContactGroups`, which is bound to the `ComboBox` is not any enumerable. I don't understand why you would bind it to a `ComboBox` in the first place.

Comment: That... Is a very good point. Its an error in my code, hang on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would implement it like this:

**View Model**:

```
public class ContactsViewModel
{    
    public IEnumerable<Contact> Contacts
    {
        get 
        { 
            return db.Contacts.Where
            (
                x => x.ContactGroupId == ContactGroup.Id &&
                x.Deleted == false
            ); 
        }
    }

    private ContactGroup _contactGroup = new ContactGroup();
    private ContactGroup ContactGroup
    {
        get { return _contactGroup; }
        set
        {
            _contactGroup = value;
            RaisePropertyChangedEvent("ContactGroup");
            RaisePropertyChangedEvent("Contacts");
        }
    }  

    private ObservableCollection<ContactGroup> _ContactGroups 
    = new ObservableCollection<ContactGroup>();
    private IEnumerable<ContactGroup> ContactGroups
    {
        get { return _ContactGroupsViewModel; }
    }  
}
```

**XAML**:

```
<!-- Select here to populate datagrid -->
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ContactGroups}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Name"
          SelectedItem="{Binding ContactGroup}" />

<!-- ComboBox selection loads data to the grid -->
<DataGrid ItemsSource={Binding Contacts}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding FirstName}" Header="First Name" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding LastName}" Header="Last Name" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Good news is the ContactGroups aren't meant to change so the setter needn't be there, but I'm still confused about how to make the ComboBox change `Contacts` so that it only contains the Contacts belonging to a specific ContactGroup

Comment: I'm not very clear on how... My brain seems to be only running on like 1/3rd capacity today. Is it because we're raising the PropertyChanged event on the setter for ContactGroup?

Comment: Yes, this way, when you change the selection in the ComboBox a new value for ContactGroup is set and the PropertyChangedEvent for Contacts is raised as well. But the XAML need to be changed to. I fogot this. I'll edit in a second.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `ContactGroup` property to your view model and execute the command, or call the `ListContactGroups()` method directly, in the setter of this one:

```
private int _contactGroup;
public int ContactGroup
{
    get { return _contactGroup; }
    set
    {
        _contactGroup = value;
        ListContactGroups();
    }
}
```

This should work since you are binding the `SelectedValue` property of the `ComboBox` to `ContactGroup` in your XAML:

```
SelectedValue="{Binding ContactGroup}" />
```

This means that this property will be set whenever you select an item in the `ComboBox`.

Comment: ListContactsForGroupCommand does not need to be an ICommand change it to a method/function and follow mm8's solution it should work fine